# The walking problems of my character -game engine-

Tags: armature

I am new to creating games and had 1 problem... I was setting things in game logic and everything went smoothly. The walk animation and stand animation of my character has no problem untill i create a box and parent the character to it... i am trying to make my character move instead of just  doing the movement . The character started moving and the animation go along with it -works fine- But there is a minor problem. The character will move up abit when i press w to move.... i didnt set anything to the z location... here is the file of my project.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/149cf046t4vvlxx/walk+cycle%282%29.blend

press p to play and press w to walk ... u will see the problem

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your armature setup, I expected a root bone which is the parent of all other bones. At first glance it looks as if you have an x-offset in your walk cycle keyframed. (I currently use only MHX rigs).